# Find specific text but not set a specific cell reference

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing an Excel macro that needs to find specific text `Client Remittance Details` and then select and cut to the end of the sheet and then paste on another tab.  The text can be in on a different row for each different workbook.  The macro always writes a specific cell reference so it errors on the next file.  Here is the section of the macro that seems to be the error.

```
Cells.Find(What:="Client Remittance Details", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
    xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
    xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

Range("A12").Select
Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
Selection.Cut
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: What do you mean by "errors on the next file"? Do you have the complete macro? Can you share the workbook some way?

Comment: In your code you are activating the found cell (that contains the text you want) - and then selecting cell `A12`. Is this intended? Assuming it is, because I cannot see the loop - your problem may be that the active cell is not being reset as you like it to be(??) depending upon what column your data is in, would changing your `Find` method to something like `After:= Worksheets("MySheetName").Range("A1")` work? You need to change sheetname and use the correct range/column, of course

Answer (score 0):

Your **Range("A12").Select** is ruining your *find.*  This:

```
Sub luxation()
    Dim r1 As Range, rCopy As Range, rPaste As Range
    Set r1 = Cells.Find(What:="Client Remittance Details", After:=Cells(1, 1), LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    Set rCopy = Range(r1, Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Set rPaste = Range("A1")
    rCopy.Copy rPaste
End Sub
```

This sets **rPaste** to cell **A1** on the newly added sheet.